# How to print the type of object in string.format

Tags: c#

I have a Lion class and I want to print the type

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
     return String.Format("{0} This is a  [{2}] Called {1}", SpeciesName,   GoesBy );   

    }
```

What I want to say "Cat This is a [Lion]   Called Felix

Comment: Does Lion inherit from Cat?

Comment: Where is `Lion` coming from? I don't see any `Lion` in your string. Your format expects 3 parameters but you passed just 2.

Comment: no. All I want to know is how to print the type of the object ??

Comment: Lion is the class thats what I want it to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GetType().Name

```
public override string ToString()
{
 return String.Format("{0} This is a  [{2}] Called {1}", GetType().Name, SpeciesName,   GoesBy );   

}
```

Comment: Works put also prints the namespace eg AnimalKingdom.Lion

Comment: Use one of the properties on Type (returned by GetType) that returns just the type name.... Probably Type.Name but I can't remember, msdn or intellisense will confirm

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `Lion class`, which inherits from `Cat class`:

then in `Lion class`:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
         return String.Format("{0} This is a  [{1}] Called {2}", base.GetType(),  this.GetType(), this.Name );   
        }
```

**EDIT**: In order to give a solution different from others, this one gives you only the name(without namespace) of the `Cat` and `Lion` classes.

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
         return String.Format("{0} This is a  [{1}] Called {2}", typeof(Cat).Name,  typeof(Lion).Name, this.Name );   
        }
```

Comment: I answered this exactly the same 2 minutes before...

Comment: @EvanL And Taylor Maxwell answered the same thing before you. You answered anyway, presumably because you didn't see the other answer. Most likely, the same thing happened here.

Comment: @EvanL: Sorry for that, I have changed my answer, see the edit

Comment: Still printing namespace. Eg animalKindom.Lion ??

Comment: @Francis Gall:Did you try the second solution?, works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have somewhere in your code the following:

```
public class Lion : Cat { ... }
```

You just need to get the base type of `Lion` to show these.

```
return String.Format("{0} This is a [{1}] Called {2}", 
                     base.GetType().ToString(), //SHould give you Cat
                     this.GetType().ToString(), //Should give you Lion
                     this.GoesBy.ToString()); //Should give you Felix
```

It is hard to exactly answer your question without seeing the class declaration though.